# How to handle night vision if AutoExposure does not work

Tags: camera, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, python-gstreamer, aravis

I have a pipeline that is streaming a flir camera over rtsp like this.

```
/usr/bin/gst-launch-1.0 aravissrc ! video/x-raw,format=RGB ! videoconvert !  video/x-raw,format=I420 ! x264enc speed-preset=ultrafast ! rtspclientsink protocols=tcp location=rtsp://localhost:8554/flir
```

I am running human detection experiments on this and normally it was working okay. Recently it started giving no detections at night times so I checked the frames. They were almost all dark. I manually increased the exposure and the gain like this

```
/usr/bin/gst-launch-1.0 aravissrc gain=25 exposure=100000 ...
```

and it returns the expected frames with this setting but this setting is not compatible to the daylight. So I decided to use AutoExposure like this

```
/usr/bin/gst-launch-1.0 aravissrc gain=25 features="BalanceWhiteAuto=Continuous ExposureAuto=Continuous" ...
```

but it does not return the frame with expected light. So I am out of options here except to write a service to dynamically changing `exposure` value based on time but I think it is the job of the camera software. What should I do here? Is there any other plugins or features with gstreamer that can fix my problem?

I am not able to find great documentation on aravissrc and its features.